# Coordinates in a new coordinate space defined by three points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have three 3D points A,B,C in a coordinate system. I want to transform the coordinates to a new coordinate system which has point A as the new origin (0, 0, 0), AB as the line along the new x-axis, and AC as the line along the new y-axis. How do I get the new coordinates of A, B, C in this new coordinates space?

Comment: A new origin and two new axis directions aren’t enough to specific the new coordinate system completely. You still have to choose the new $z$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define three vectors.

$X$ is the new $x$ axis $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}$, $Y$ is the new y axis $\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\\ y_2  \\ y_3\end{pmatrix}$, and $Z$ is the new z axis $\begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\\ z_2 \\ z_3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Then, we can make this transformation matrix $T$ that converts coordinates from from the new coordinate system to the old coordinate system. This is $T=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix}$.

The opposite of this, which is what we want, is the matrix $T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$.

Now, when we have coordinates in the old system, and we want to convert to a new system, we can simply use $v ' = T^{-1}v$, where $v$ is a vector representing the old coordinates and $v'$ is a vector representing the new coordinates.

---

Since there is a translation involved, where we translate everything by $-\vec{A}$, where $\vec{A}$ is the coordinates of the old point $A$, we should use  $v ' = T^{-1}(v-\vec{A})$ instead.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/scalar-vector-matrix.html

Comment: how to multiply vectors and matrices

Comment: Sorry, I do not completely understand. It seems that b1, b2, c1, c2 refer to the new coordinate system? Since these are 3D points, shouldn't it be AB is (0, b1, b2) and AC is (c1, 0, c2)?

Comment: oh, what? is the z axis unchanged?

Comment: from your question, i assumed yours was just an xy plane

Comment: let me redo my answer

Comment: The line orthogonal to AB and AC will be the new z-axis, I suppose?

Comment: yup, that's possible. however, i should let you know that there are coordinate spaces where not all of the axes are orthogonal, it's interesting

Comment: The overall development is good, but there’s a translation involved, so the transformation can’t be represented by a single $3\times3$ matrix.

Comment: @amd ah i see, but where did he mention that

Comment: Second sentence: “... which has point $A$ as the new origin $(0,0,0)$.”

Comment: @amd oh wow! i see it now. for some reason when i first saw the question. i interpreted as A is origin before and after, and AB and BC were the x and y axes, in a 2 dimesnional system. thanks for explanining it. let me edit my ansewr now